# Using Texture (AsyncDisplayKit) in Swift, How do i prevent a flicker when I scroll past the bottom of the last ASCellNode in an ASTableNode?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, asyncdisplaykit

Using Texture (AsyncDisplayKit) in Swift, How do i prevent a flicker when I scroll past the bottom of the last ASCellNode in an ASTableNode?

In my implementation, I found one issue. I am not overriding the UIScrollViewDelegate, and if I scroll past the bottom of the last cell, the content seems to jump even higher then I have stretched it before animating back to being level with the bottom inset. Is this a known issue, or is there some option that may prevent this?

Using a single ASTableNode with 4 vertical nodes that just over 2 of display on the screen at once.

The jump y distance seems to be somewhere around 1/5 of the distance that I scroll past the bottom. So even on the slightest pull up if I let go it has a mini flicker.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
func shouldBatchFetch(for tableNode: ASTableNode) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

This fixed my issue.